# How to use an integer as a JSON object Key

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to use an integer as a **JSON** object key :

```
let myJKey = 1  

let myJSONArrayObject = { filter: [] }  

myJSONObject.filter.push({myJKey: 'a json value'})  

However, I get : `{"filter":[{"myJKey":{"a json value"}}]}`
```

How should I set up so the I get the value **1** in the `myKey` variable as the JSON key?

Comment: You want to set value of myJKey to that object right ?

Comment: Firstly, you have a JS object, not JSON. Secondly, JSON and JavaScript object keys can only be strings, by specification. At best, your key can be `"1"`, never `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[]` **(Bracket notation)**

```js
let myJKey = 1  

let myJSONArrayObject = { filter: [] }  

myJSONArrayObject.filter.push({[myJKey]: 'a json value'})  

console.log(myJSONArrayObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing []

```
myJSONArrayObject.filter.push({[myJKey]: 'a json value'})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myJSONObject.filter.push({myJKey: 'a json value'})
```

Should be:-

```
myJSONObject.filter.push({[myJKey]: 'a json value'})
```

This is a ES6 syntax. Supporting in many browsers